# Error while fitting the data in KNN in python

Tags: python-3.x, data-science

This is my code

```
clf = KNN(n_neighbors = 1)

clf.fit(train_x, train_y)

train_predict = clf.predict(train_x)
k = f1_score(train_predict,train_y)
print("Training F1 Score:",k)

test_predict = clf.predict(test_x)
k = f1_score(test_predict,test_y)
print("Test F1 score:",k)
```

I am getting the error

```
Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [668, 223]
```

The shape of the data is
 train_x=(668, 24),
train_y=(223,24)

Please help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation of the fit function

> Fit the model using X as training data and y as target values
>
> Parameters:
>   X : {array-like, sparse matrix, BallTree, KDTree}
>   Training data. If array or matrix, shape [n_samples, n_features], or [n_samples, n_samples] if metric=’precomputed’.
>
> y : {array-like, sparse matrix}
>   Target values of shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_outputs]

It is clear that the shape of train_x and train_y doesn't match the requirements of the fit function. I am guessing that dimensions of the train_x and train_y are flipped in your case.

Therefore try:

```
clf.fit(train_x.T, train_y.T)
```